# GORM issues with Grails 2.0.M1

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm having trouble with my domain object saving when I have a complex relationship.

the offending class `NativeEntryEntityPersister` is in the jar grails-datastore-core-1.0.0.M7.jar. Does anybody know where I could get a hold of the sources for  this?

My grails installation's src folder doesn't have the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/engine/NativeEntryEntityPersister.java